# How to pass argument to php file using a drush command?

Tags: drush

I've small php script in my public folder called sample.php. I run this file using drush command **drush scr sample.php**.

I want to know how to pass argument to php file using drush command and how to get arguments in php file?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is explained quite nicely in `drush topic scripts`.

Your script should start with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env drush
<?php
```

Then, you may call your script directly. For example, if you have saved your script in a file called `myscript`, then you would call it via:

```
$ myscript a b --flag=bar
```

Drush provides a method called `drush_shift` that allows you to access you one at a time:

```
$first = drush_shift();
$second = drush_shift();
```

In the above example, `$first` will be `a` and `$second` will be `b`.  You may access your options via `drush_get_option()` as usual.

```
$flag = drush_get_option('flag');
$other = drush_get_option('other', 'default');
```

In the above example, `$flag` is `bar` and `other` is `$default'.

Note that you can use `$argv` as suggested in the other answer, but if you do this, your arguments and options will be mixed together, and you will need to parse them yourself.  Using `drush_shift()` and `drush_get_option();` is more convenient.

Comment: Using `drush_shift()` and `drush_get_option()` also works without making the script directly executable. Perhaps the answer should reflect that as well by marking the relevant part as optional.

Answer (score 3):

On Drush 10, I managed to work with:

```
<?php
$first = $extra[0];
$second = $extra[1];
```

Calling script with

```
./vendor/bin/drush php:script scripts/my-script.php -- firstarg secondarg
```

Answer (score 2):

Posible Solucion:

```
$_SERVER['argv'][3]
```

Comand:

```
drush scr 'testScript.php' field
```

Now, $_SERVER['argv'][3] = **field**

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

In php command line you can use pass arguments to your script and inside your script grab it by using $argv variable:

check this out: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

Comment: what is the drush command?

Comment: The drush command is: Drush scr.There is a way to make Drush compatible by adding in the script file header 
#!/usr/bin/env drush
and use $arg = drush_shift() to get the arguments as an array

Comment: can u provide sample command?

Comment: Just as summary of all previous answers and practical example as also as answer to the question above.  
  
You can run something like this: `drush scr path/to/script --id=15`.
And then if your script starts with `#!/usr/bin/env drush` (as @greg_1_anderson mentioned) than you can get your parameter via `$id = drush_get_option('id');` inside this script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an environment variable:

```
MY_FLAG=value drush do_something
```

In php you can then retrieve this variable:

```
echo $_SERVER['MY_FLAG'];
```